# Что означает конструкция <'_> после типа?

Tags: rust

В коде на Rust (из книги "Rust в действии") увидел такой фрагмент:

```rust
impl fmt::Display for UpstreamError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}
```

Смутил тип аргумента `f` - `fmt::Formatter<'_>`. Вопрос - что означает конструкция `<'_>` после типа?

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил, если нет, пишите в комментариях.

*PS: в интернете искал, но ничего не нашёл.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный тип требует generic-параметр lifetime, а конструкция <'_> предлагает компилятору автоматически вывести требуемый lifetime.
Например, если нужно вернуть из функции итератор, то нужно объявить её примерно так:

```
fn foo() -> impl Iterator<Item = SomeType> + <'_>
```

т.к. итератор содержит ссылку на итерируемый объект и мы должны соблюсти время жизни этой ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

lifetime. После одинарной кавычки пишется любое имя лайфтайма, кроме зарезервированного `'static`.

Comment: А по подробнее?

Comment: @wchistow [Validating References with Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html)